# Random scripts stop working on all websites in Windows XP

Tags: browser, windows-registry, javascript

I have been searching with finding any solution. Random scripts stopped working on websites.

For example, on my own website the jQuery scripts aren't working, and when I click on them in the source code, they link to a not found page. Although some other scripts still seem to work, many don't, and this goes for other wbesites I've tried too. I reinstalled Java and ran a registry check, but nothing helped. Do you have any idea?

I am using Windows XP.

Comment: What browser do u use?

Comment: By any chance "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options." ? I know jQuery has updated some HTTP headers to block "abuse"

Comment: I tried it in all of them. I think what actually happened was flowplayer.org lost their jquery files. I was using their tabbed content tool and the script stopped working. It didnt link to anything anymore. I had my own copy thought an added it to my ftp and changed the link and not it workds again. So I think that everyone that is using their tools might be experiencing same problem.

Comment: @PolluxKhafra If you've fixed your problem all together, put an answer down and accept it when you can. I read it as all website scripts stopped working and your comment seems to mention your own website. Have you solved one of the problems or the overall problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a jquery library with flowplayer.org went missing causing the scripts not to work.